# ROS project feasibility / newbee question

Tags: ros, arduino, android, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm absolutely new to ROS, just completed my environment on Ubuntu 12.04 and passed 2 tutorils of Hello World and Blink using Arduino.

My hardware setup is this:

[E:=Ethernet@RJ45]

Robot:
Android 4.0(+rosjava?) <--> E <--> Router_openWRT <--> E <--> Arduino <--> sensors+motors

User:
pc<--> wifi <--> Router_openWRT

Happy-path scenario:

The User presses arrow keys of the keyboard on internet and moves the robot, while seeing the enviroment using an ip-camera on the router of the robot.

Questions:

1. What should I port as a minimal set to OpenWRT so that it can manage the communication between the User, Arduino and Android? May be the best approach is keeping it just for security and firewall between internet and robot, while in the local network of the robot Android and Arduino communicate simply over TCP? If so, what would be the guarantee of reliablity for the communication, specially so that Arduino receives any command once, and in the right order and Android receives the sensor data guaranteed?
2. What is the best practice suggested by Gurus of ROS for such an implementation? I'm still some confuses (1st day of installing ROS).

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42804/ros-project-feasibility-/-newbee-question/) by [rosgreeting](https://answers.ros.org/users/3122/rosgreeting/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you're making things more complicated for yourself. Why do you need to run anything on your router other than network routing?

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0